# Drawflow Angular 16 flowchart using Drawflow

Tags: angular, flowchart, angular16

I'm using Drawflow in my Angular v16(standalone) app. but i can't implement the package completely.

I want to show the work flow of a document with stage, status based to show the user the complete flow of the application and it's functionalities.

Comment: This is not a question.